# Manually replace elements in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,2,5]
for key in a:
    if key == 2:
        key = 10
print key
```

Result: `[1,10,3,10,4,10,5]`

I need Python to "ask" manually which of the elements to replace.

Comment: What do you mean by ask? something like `input`

Comment: That's a `list`, not a `dictionary` :3

Comment: @Ryan Saxe yup. something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for indx, ele in enumerate(a):
    if ele == 2:
        a[indx] = 10
print a
```

Prints:

```
[1, 10, 3, 10, 4, 10, 5]
```

---

If the value you want to change is an input, then simply just do:

```
change = map(int, raw_input("What number do you want to change in the list? And what number should it be? Separate both numbers with a space ").split())
for indx, _ in enumerate(a):
    if change[0] == 2:
        a[indx] = change[1]
```

Or as a list comprehension (If you like this solution upvote Ashwini's :)):

```
change = map(int, raw_input("What number do you want to change in the list? And what number should it be? Separate both numbers with a space ").split())
[change[1] if x == change[0] else x for x in a]
```

Comment: actually i want to input variable by myself. and replace only one variable from this list

Comment: @AlexEfremo I don't understand. What will you input?

Comment: i will input from keyboard

Comment: @AlexEfremo yea, but when the input screen comes up, will you input the number you want to change and the number that you want to change it to? That's what my code does, and so I'm just clarifying :3

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, so you must convert them to integers first.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oops, forgot about that.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,2,4,2,5]
>>> a[:] = [10 if x==2 else x for x in a]
>>> a
[1, 10, 3, 10, 4, 10, 5]
```

If you want to replace multiple items then consider using a dict:

```
>>> dic = {2 : 10}
>>> a[:] = [dic.get(x,x) for x in a]
>>> a
[1, 10, 3, 10, 4, 10, 5]
```

Comment: Actually, this is probably better. +1

Comment: +1 — this is exactly what I was typing! [_List comprehension_](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) seems like the right answer here.